# Find vector that creates similar angles with given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is my first question here. I'm really stuck.

I am preparing for a test, and I'm having trouble with a type of question.

This is the question:

```
 Given 3 vectors: U(1,0,0) V(1,0,2) W(0,1,3).
 Find vector T(a,b,c) that creates equal angles with vectors U, V, and W.
```

Mind you guys, I am not interested in the answer. I have the answer. The reason I am asking this, is in order to find a strategy to solve those types of questions.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the relation between dot products and angles, we need to find a $t = (a,b,c)$ (which we will assume to be normalized) such that

$$ t\cdot u = t \cdot \frac{v}{\| v \|} = t \cdot \frac{w}{\| w \| },$$

i.e.,

$$a = \frac{a + 2c}{\sqrt 5} = \frac{b+3c}{\sqrt {10}}.$$

Comparing these three quantities pairwise gives you a system of three homogeneous linear equations in three unknowns that you can solve.

Comment: You made it so simple! Thank you!

Comment: @GuySeltenreich You're very welcome :-)